# htaccess https off only for specified routes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to force https://www.domain.com on my domain **excluding** some routes.

**301 Redirections**:

1. domain.com => https://www.domain.com (not working)
2. www.domain.com => https://www.domain.com (not working)
3. http://www.domain.com => https://www.domain.com (not working)

**Excludes**:

1. http://www.domain.com/init => http://www.domain.com/init
2. http://www.domain.com/posts => http://www.comain.com/posts
3. ...

What I have done so far:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(init|posts) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|website|favicon\.ico|style\.css|sitemap.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its funny I am searching a day for a solution and just found that my excluding routes first get resolved to http://www.domain.com/index.php/init and don't match my condition so by adding the same rule to **QUERY_STRING** now works as expected:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(init|posts) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(init|posts) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|website|favicon\.ico|style\.css|sitemap.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]
```